# Filldown with outerapply

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, outer-apply

My source data is following

```
    declare @dim as table
(
    name varchar(10),period int
)
insert into @dim
select * from
(
    values
        ('a', 202001),('a', 202002),('a', 202003),('a', 202004),
        ('a', 202005),('a', 202006),('a', 202007),('a', 202008),
        ('a', 202009),('a', 202010),('a', 202011),('a', 202012),
        ('b', 202001),('b', 202002),('b', 202003),('b', 202004),
        ('b', 202005),('b', 202006),('b', 202007),('b', 202008),
        ('b', 202009),('b', 202010),('b', 202011),('b', 202012)
) t (one, two)


declare @fact as table
(
    name varchar(max),period bigint,val decimal(19, 2)
)
insert into @fact
select * from
(
    values
        ('a', 202002, 100),
        ('a', 202005, 600),
        ('a', 202010, 700),
        ('b', 202004, 500),
        ('b', 202007, 600),
        ('b', 20208, 1000)
) t (one, two, three)
```

I was wondering if it is possible at all to achieve a fill-down inside an `outer-apply`. I tried as following but it did not work

```
select a.name,a.period,x.val, y.FD
from @dim a
outer apply (select * from @fact b where a.name=b.name and a.period=b.period) as x
outer apply (select max(x.val) over (partition by a.name order by a.period ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)) as y (FD)
```

The reason why I am keen on achieving the fill down inside `outer-apply` because I can keep on utilizing that filled down column from `outer-apply` in the same query in succeeding `apply` to create further calculated columns or transformation without the help of any temp table as following

```
select a.name,a.period,x.val, y.FD, z.bucket
from @dim a
outer apply (select * from @fact b where a.name=b.name and a.period=b.period) as x
outer apply (successful fill down) as y (FD)
outer apply (VALUES(CASE WHEN FD>1000 then 'bucket1' else 'bucket2' end) as z(bucket)
```

My desired result

| name | period | val | FD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 202001 | NULL | NULL |
| a | 202002 | 100.00 | 100.00 |
| a | 202003 | NULL | 100.00 |
| a | 202004 | NULL | 100.00 |
| a | 202005 | 600.00 | 600.00 |
| a | 202006 | NULL | 600.00 |
| a | 202007 | NULL | 600.00 |
| a | 202008 | NULL | 600.00 |
| a | 202009 | NULL | 600.00 |
| a | 202010 | 700.00 | 700.00 |
| a | 202011 | NULL | 700.00 |
| a | 202012 | NULL | 700.00 |
| b | 202001 | NULL | NULL |
| b | 202002 | NULL | NULL |
| b | 202003 | NULL | NULL |
| b | 202004 | 500.00 | 500.00 |
| b | 202005 | NULL | 500.00 |
| b | 202006 | NULL | 500.00 |
| b | 202007 | 600.00 | 600.00 |
| b | 202008 | NULL | 600.00 |
| b | 202009 | NULL | 600.00 |
| b | 202010 | NULL | 600.00 |
| b | 202011 | NULL | 600.00 |
| b | 202012 | NULL | 600.00 |

Which can be achieved by following but outside of an `outer-apply` which I am not looking for.

```
select a.name,a.period,x.val, MAX(x.val) over (partition by a.name order by a.period ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as FD
from @dim a
outer apply (select * from @fact b where a.name=b.name and a.period=b.period) as x
```

Comment: What is a "fill down inside"? For the sample data you've provided, what are your expected results? What is the logic to get said results?

Comment: Thanks Larnu. I am going to edit my question to give you the expected result soon.

Comment: To me "fill down" is something you do in Excel to replicate data or a formula down the rows in a particular column; not a term I use in reference to SQL queries. What does it mean to you?

Comment: Why not just use a subquery? [Example on db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=abdfc2c04a784bac4a584988698d3616). Also, your first `OUTER APPLY` could very easily be a `LEFT JOIN`. In reality it doesn't matter, the optimiser will recognise that and execute it as a join internally, but you shouldn't necessarily rely on the optimiser simplifying your query for you, if you can simplify it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is that you are putting the `MAX` window function inside an `APPLY`.**

When you use an `APPLY`, the whole subquery is (logically) evaluated for each row. So the subquery, which only contains a `select`, only has one row, and that is evaluated per row of the outer table.

**You *cannot* use window functions in this way.** Window functions are only (logically) evaluated after joining and grouping, in the `select` phase and before ordering. The `APPLY` comes in the join phase, which is earlier.

> Note that your first `APPLY` can be rewritten as a simple `LEFT JOIN`.

```sql
select
    a.name,
    a.period,
    x.val, 
    FD = max(x.val) over 
         (partition by a.name
         order by a.period ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
from @dim a
left join @fact x on a.name = x.name and a.period = x.period
```

If you want the `MAX` to be used in other parts of the query, you *must* place it in a derived table.

```sql
select *,
  SomeOtherCalculationInvolvingFD
from (
  select
    a.name,
    a.period,
    x.val, 
    FD = max(x.val) over 
         (partition by a.name
         order by a.period ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
  from @dim a
  left join @fact x on a.name = x.name and a.period = x.period
) t
```

I leave you with one tip: `APPLY` is very useful, but don't go round hammering every nail with it. Understand how it works, use appropriately.